# T-SQL - WHERE @Parameter LIKE column+'%'

Tags: t-sql, wildcard, sql-like

I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @phone varchar(50) = '972544123123'
SELECT top 1 prefix_number
FROM prefix_numbers 
WHERE @phone LIKE LTRIM(RTRIM(prefix_number)) + '%' 
ORDER BY len(prefix_number) DESC
```

It is used to find the shortest prefix for a phone number.
This is not sargable, and results in a table scan.
Do you have any ideas on how to rewrite this?

the output for this is 972, where all possible prefixes are 9725 & 972.

Comment: Why are you trimming `prefix_number` ?

Comment: `LEN` also ignores trailing spaces (I assume why you're using `TRIM`?) so a value like `'123________'` would be seen as "shorter" than `'123456'` with `LEN` (note I use `'_'` to represent `' '` due to comments no allowing repeated whitespace characters). If you want to include whitespace, `DATALENGTH` would be a better option.

Comment: The app inserts prefix_number with white spaces.Thank you, it is good to know. Do you know of a way to search in a better way that wont do an entire table scan?

Comment: You could create a trigger for insert/update to trim the `prefix_number` for you, then you wouldn't have to do it in the query.... You can also create a persisted computed column for the length of the `prefix_number` and index that as well, if you still suffer a performance hit on the select statement

Comment: @ZoharPeled The computed column is a great idea, the problem is I don't have a way of knowing how long the prefix is, it varies.

Comment: Why do you care how long it is? anyway you have a maximum possible length of the column (even for a `varchar(max)`, which seems like the wrong data type for this kind of thing)

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: The `LTrim` is a red herring and all prefixes are store as right-filled fixed-length strings.

The following code should be able to use an index on `Prefix` in the table of prefixes. It breaks the target phone number (`@Phone`) into substrings from one character up to the length of the number, then performs a join on equality with the available prefixes. Using `top 1` and `order by` it retrieves the shortest (or longest) match, if any.

```
declare @Prefixes as Table ( PrefixId Int Identity, Prefix Char(50) );
insert into @Prefixes ( Prefix ) values
  ( '914' ), ( '972544' ), ( 'BR549' ), ( '972' );
select PrefixId, '''' + Prefix + '''' as Prefix -- Show blank padding.
  from @Prefixes;

declare @Phone as VarChar(50) = '972544123123';

with
  Substrings as (
    select 1 as Length, Cast( Left( @Phone, 1 ) as VarChar(50) ) as TargetPrefix
    union all
    select Length + 1, Left( @Phone, Length + 1 )
      from Substrings
      where Length + 1 <= Len( @Phone )
    )
  -- select * from Substrings; -- Use this to see the intermediate results.
  select top 1 P.PrefixId, P.Prefix
    from @Prefixes as P inner join
      Substrings as S on P.Prefix = S.TargetPrefix
    order by S.Length; -- Ascending for shortest match, descending for longest match.
```

If you have a *tally* (or *numbers*) table it may be more efficient to use it to split the string into substrings.